# thrust transform performance number

Tags: asynchronous, cuda, benchmarking, synchronous, thrust

Can any body tell me that thrust routines are blocking or non blocking?
I want to time it, here are the code snippets-

**code snippet -1:**

```
clock_t start,end;
start = clock();
thrust::transform( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), thrust::negate<int>());
end  = clock();
```

**code snippet - 2**

```
clock_t start,end;
start = clock();
thrust::transform( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), thrust::negate<int>());
cudaThreadSynchronize();
end  = clock();
```

**code snippet -1** is taking very less time in compare to **code snippet -2**
why is this happening? and which one is the right way to time the thrust routines so that i may compare it to my parallel code.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe Thrust formally defines which APIs are blocking and which are non-blocking anywhere in the documentation. However, a transform call like your example should be executed in a single back-end closure operation (which translates into a single kernel call without host-device data copies) and should be asynchronous.

Your second code snippet is closer to the correct way to time a Thrust operation, but note that

1. `clock()` is generally implemented using a low resolution time source and is probably not suitable for timing these types of operations. You should find a higher resolution host source timer, or better still, use the CUDA events API to time your code. You can see an example of how to use these APIs [in this question-answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6959213/681865).
2. `cudaThreadSynchronize` is a deprecated API as of the CUDA 4.0 release. You should use `cudaDeviceSynchronize` instead.